# Parseval's Identity Proof Monotone/Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, parsevals-identity

I proved Parseval's identity as follows:

> If $f\in L^2\left(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\right)$, then
>   \begin{equation*}
> \int\left|f\left(t\right)\right|^2\,dt=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|c\left(n\right)\right|^2.
> \end{equation*}
>   *Proof.*
>   \begin{align*}
> \int\left|f\left(t\right)\right|^2\,dt&=\int\left|\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c\left(n\right)\exp\left(2\pi int\right)\right|^2\,dt\\
> &=\int\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c\left(n\right)\exp\left(2\pi int\right)\overline{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c\left(n\right)\exp\left(2\pi int\right)}\,dt\\
> &=\int\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c\left(n\right)\exp\left(2\pi int\right)\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\overline{c\left(n\right)}\exp\left(-2\pi int\right)\,dt\\
> &=\sum_{n,k\in\mathbb{Z}}c\left(n\right)\overline{c\left(k\right)}\int\exp\left(2\pi it\left(k-n\right)\right)\,dt\tag{$*$}\\
> &=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|c\left(n\right)\right|^2.\tag*{$\blacksquare$}
> \end{align*}

However, I took a leap of faith with equality $\left(*\right)$. How can I justify moving the infinite sum outside? I know that I need the monotone/dominated convergence theorem, but I do not know how to show that
\begin{equation*}
g_{n,k}\left(t\right)=c\left(n\right)\overline{c\left(k\right)}\exp\left(2\pi it\left(k-n\right)\right)
\end{equation*}
satisfies the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually $L^{2}({\bf{R}}/{\bf{Z}})$ can be identified with $L^{2}[0,1]$, so $|g_{n,k}(t)|\leq|c(n)|\cdot|c(k)|$ and $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}|c(n)|\cdot|c(k)|dt=|c(n)|\cdot|c(k)|<\infty$, so Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem goes through.

Comment: I see! But then I need to show $(c(n))_n$ is in $\ell^2$ also! Thanks!